# How to analyze whether the function $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0 \atop y \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x, y)}{|x|+|y|}$ is differentiable at point $(0, 0)$

Tags: limits, derivatives

If $f(x, y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, which of the following propositions is correct:

$$\begin{array}{c}
&(A)& \text{If the limit}  \lim _{x \rightarrow 0 \atop y \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x, y)}{|x|+|y|}  \text{exists},\text{then}  f(x, y)  \text{is differentiable at (0,0)} \\
&(B)& \text{If the limit}   \lim _{x \rightarrow 0 \atop y \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x, y)}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \text{exists},\text{then}   f(x, y)  \text{is differentiable at (0,0)} \\
&(C)& \text{If f(x, y) is differentiable at (0,0)},\text{the limit}   \lim _{x \rightarrow 0 \atop y \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x, y)}{|x|+|y|}  \text{exists} \\
&(D)& \text{If f(x, y) is differentiable at (0,0)},\text{the limit}   \lim _{x \rightarrow 0 \atop y \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x, y)}{x^{2}+y^{2}}  \text{exists}
\end{array}$$

The answer is `B`, but I want to know why the `A` option is incorrect.

Comment: One can construct any number of counterexamples involving hyperoscillatory trig functions, but instead consider $f(x,y) = |x|+|y|$

Answer (score 2):

(A) is false.  Take, for example, $f(x,y) = |x| + |y|$.  Then $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}^2$, the given limit is $1$, and $f$ is not differentiable on either coordinate axis (nor the origin).

(This $f$ is differentiable on the interior of each quadrant and its derivative is constant on each of these four pieces.)

[image: Mathematica graphics]